# Confused by notation for Mathematical Induction question

Tags: proof-verification, induction

The question says to allow $x_1=3$ and given $x_n$:

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{4}x_n + 9.$$
Use mathematical induction to prove that for all $n \in\mathbb N$:
(a) $x_{n+1}> x_n$,
(b) $x_n < 12$.

I am not completely sure I know what's being asked here. Could someone clarify and give a hint.. I think I at least got the base case.. Compare the equation with 3 and then the equation with 4. Or is that wrong, too?

Comment: You are asked to use mathematical induction. Have a look on this site (google mathematical induction, and the formula). For $n=1$, did you verify both statements already?

Comment: Is "1/4x<sub>n</sub>" supposed to be $\frac14 x_n$ or $\frac{1}{4x_n}$?

Comment: The former rather than the latter

Comment: for the base case, if $x_1=3$ can you get $x_2$ from the equation? What is $x_2$ in terms of $x_1$?

Comment: To save yourself some work note that $x_{n+1} - x_n = \frac{3}{4}\left(12 - x_n\right)$ so proving $x_{n+1} > x_n$ is the same as proving $12 > x_n$.

Comment: @Winther how did you get the $\frac{3}{4}$? I don't even understand how $x_{n+1}-x_{n} = \frac{3}{4}(12 - x_{n})$ I thought if you got $x_{n}=4*(x_{n+1}-9)$ you'd have $\frac{x_n}{4}+9 - 4*(x_{n+1}-9)$ But I guess I am just all around super lost.

Comment: This is just very basic algebra: if $A  = B$ then $A - C = B - C$. Here $A = x_{n+1}$, $B = \frac{1}{4}x_n + 9$ and $C = x_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start first by proving part b. If $x_{n-1}<12$ then $\frac{1}{4}x_{n-1}<3$, therefore $x_n<3+9=12$.

For part a, just compute $x_{n+1}-x_n$. You will get $9-\frac{3}{4}x_n$. But now you know $x_n<12$, so $x_{n+1}-x_n>9-\frac{3}{4}12$

Comment: Hm.. I like the idea of that approach, but can we back up for a minute. For the base case, I was under the impression that I would just compare $x_{1}$ (3) and $x_{2}$ which is $1/4*3+9$ and that would be sufficient to prove the base case. Is that correct?

And how did $x_{n+1} - x_{n} = 9-(3/4)x_{n}$

Edited because I am trying to be better about formatting in latex or whatever it's called

Comment: Yes. I skipped that base case step. The general case is tricky. I do not know how to prove a without b.

Comment: Yeah, I absolutely think you're correct about b and I emailed my professor. He basically said as much. Could you just elaborate a little more on why $x_{n} < 3 + 9$? I understand that $x_{n-1} < 12$, but I don't understand why we divided by 4 and where exactly the 9 came from (unless we only did that because we found that $1/4 x_{n-1} < 3$ in which case that makes sense).

Comment: That's exactly why.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the help. I've done mathematical induction before, but it's usually on sums and series. This is very different than what I have seen before.

Comment: Okay, I'm actually still lost. I thought I understood it. I understand $x_{n-1}<12$ because we are given $x_{n}<12$. I also understand that $\frac{1}{4}x_{n-1} < 3 $ because it would have to be after dividing both sides by 4 (I don't understand why it has to be 4 as opposed to 6 or something, but okay). Where did you get $x_{n+1}-x_{n}=9- \frac{3}{4}x_{n}$?

Comment: Started with $x_{n+1}=9+x_n/4$. You subtract $x_n$ from both sides. And since I divide by $4$ in this equation, that's why I am using division by 4 in the rest of the problem.